# Swift NSURL nil when running the application

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

When I run the application Xcode told me that 
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
at the url but the url isn't nil, can someone help?

here is the code

```
import Foundation

protocol WeatherUndergroundServiceByGeographicalDelegate{

    func setWeatherByGeographical(weather:WeatherUnderground)
}

class WeatherUndergoundServiceByGeographical{

    var delegate:WeatherUndergroundServiceByGeographicalDelegate?

    func getWeatherFromWeatherUnderground(latitude:Double, longitude:Double){

        let path = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/48675fd2f5485cff/conditions/geolookup/q/\(latitude,longitude).json"
        let url = NSURL(string: path)


        //session
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()


//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Error is at here~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            //parsing json weather condition from weather api. using swiftyJson
            let name = json["current_observation"]["display_location"]["city"].string
            let temp = json["current_observation"]["temp_c"].double
            let windsp = json["current_observation"]["wind_mph"].double

            //prasing the weather data
            let weather = WeatherUnderground(cityName: name!, temperature: temp!, windSpeed: windsp!)

            if self.delegate != nil{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    self.delegate?.setWeatherByGeographical(weather)

                })
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }


}
```

Comment: print(path) and post it here what is the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have error in your path string, try this:

```
let path = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/48675fd2f5485cff/conditions/geolookup/q/\(latitude),\(longitude).json"
```

The reason is that you are interpolating tuple value `\(latitude,longitude)` in the string, which adds extra space and makes url string invalid because space is not percent-escaped.
Instead you have to interpolate each value with a comma between them: `\(latitude),\(longitude)`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> let path = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/48675fd2f5485cff/conditions/geolookup/q/\(latitude,longitude).json"
> ```

I think you mean:

```
let path = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/48675fd2f5485cff/conditions/geolookup/q/\(latitude),\(longitude).json"
```